# Creating Descriptions In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

***backstory:*** I am attempting to make a spreadsheet to print and give to our customers when they order cabinets. However the cabinet catalog is extensive, and to write out the descriptions of the cabinet for each order would take too much time.

I would like to be able to put a code in A1 that would compile a description in B1. I thought VLOOKUP would do this, but it seems to stop short of what I need.

For example, if I type 'B24' in A1, I need for B1 to produce '24 inch Base Cabinet' (or something similar). It would get the size from "24" and the cabinet type from "B". Next, if I put B3D36 in A2, it should produce '36 inch Three Drawer Base Cabinet' in B2. Once again, it would get the size from '36' and the cabinet type from 'B3D'.

[image: Example of descriptions]

Am I making any sense? I tried VLOOKUP, a nested VLOOKUP, and researched INDEX MATCH, but I don't think it will help me either. Can someone lend some assistance? Thanks!

Comment: Its not that it cannot be done, its that it would have made life easier 8).  You can always check to determine if the last character is a digit or a number.  It may be easier to go through with VBA.  I personally prefer to stick with formulas for as long as I can.  if your database is relatively small, instead of breaking up the list, like you have, you could keep the code together as a unique ID and essentially have description line for each size and hinge side. So assuming a product came in every size and with a hinge on either side you would have at most 22 entries for each product

Comment: This method would work perfectly but makes for a bloated database.  The building of the data base is not so bad in Excel as you can copy and paste for multiple rows where the description is not changing.  You can have multiple columns with additional corresponding information.  IE size, cost, manufacturing time, shipping costs, etc.  Works nicely with a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH as you just have to indicate which column you want to pull info from.  HOWEVER, I believe its usually preferable to keep your data base from what you need to pull, that you cannot directly get from the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two things:

1. A list of descriptions for each Cabinet Type (like column D in the image)
2. The size extracted from the right of your code.

Let's suppose the columns C and D have your Cabinet Types and Descriptions respectively. Let's also suppose that your size is always two digits. Then you can do the following:

```
=RIGHT(A1,2)&" inch "&INDEX(D:D,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),C:C,0))
```

This takes the right two characters (the size), adds the word "inch" and then looks up the description from C and D.

For the more general case that you have more or fewer digits on the right you can use some `IF` and `VALUE` functions to handle those cases.

Comment: you could adjust the formula various ways to deal with single versus double digits.  One way is to check if pulling two right characters is a number and then proceeding accordingly.  `=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,2)),RIGHT(A1,2)&" inch "&INDEX(D:D,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),C:C,0)),RIGHT(A1,1)&" inch "&INDEX(D:D,MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),C:C,0)))`  The thought the OP had of using `VLOOKUP` would also work in this case based on how the data is layout and that the size does not have to be pulled from the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alexis & @forward, this would have worked, however I have cabinet codes with no numbers at all or a letter at the end. For example, B12L, which is a 12" base cabinet, hinged left.
I was just trying to get the basics down first before I went in deeper. I will try and work with what you gave me.

Comment: Biggest thing will be consistency with your coding.  If you make all coding equal in length, with the same character position having the same meaning you are off to the races.  Also make sure you include things like leading 0 when you have a dimension less than 2 digits long.  For hinge side you could have three possible letters, L for left, R for right and N for none....T for top and B for bottom if those are also possibilities.

Comment: @ForwardEd the only problem with that is I don't determine the coding. It comes from our cabinet company, and I can't change it. I wouldn't have to do all of this if they would just update their descriptions themselves, but they are hard-headed and I am stuck.